# Map/Reduce completion graph

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

**I'm new to Hadoop and Map/reduce Framework.
While going through the 1st program, word count problem ,I got stuck in the job details of the tracker.
What does a Map/Reduce Completion graph represents? Or in layman term ,what is represented on x,y axis?**

[image: take this as an example]

Answer (score 3):

X is the number of map/reduce tasks, and Y is the completion (a bar denotes a single task) in percent.

Comment: i.e. y shows the time taken out of whole to do the copy/sort/reduce.
ex. 30% of time taken by copy phase? Is it what it refers to .
and Thankyou .

Comment: @user2518829 nope, copy and sort will both take ~33,3% in the progress. Progress is an artificial metric and doesn't correlate strongly with time.